# Google Spreadsheet: Calculate Total Dividend generated from a particular date

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am trying to calculate dividend earned from a stock since it was bought (i.e. from a particular date). Is there a way to calculate sum of every dividend paid out by company since particular date?  For simplicity, lets assume that shares were bought only once and no additional shares were bought since then.
To make my question more clear, consider the below situation:

**Hypothetical Example:**

`Stock: AAPL 
Cost Basis : $100
Shares: 10
Date Bought: 04/22/2015`

I am attempting to calculate how much total dividend, one would earned over the past 3 years 2 months? I couldn't find an attribute from the post [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en), that would help my use case. Using Google Finance calls, as a formula for a cell value, I think only the past 12-month is yield is available, not more than that.
Can this be achieved for cell value in spreadsheet using formula so there it can updated automatically, without manually updating data every time there is payout? I am not interested in the exact dates when the dividends were paid out, just the amounts.

Thanks